# path undefined in jquery

Tags: html, javascript, css, jquery

I want to find path of file and for this I am using

```
$('#changefilename')[0].files[0].path
```

inside jquery but I am finding **Undefined**, Although I am using same process some place and finding desired output correctly but at this place I am finding wrong output.
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krdheeraj/4gfnac4t/3/)

if someone is familiar with this problem then Kindly help me.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15201258/133203)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/c2ueqebc/1/

Comment: your mention code gives path of url but I want to path of attach file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking for.

Let's take a look on your file object:

`console.log($('#changefilename')[0].files[0]);`

(Took the first random file on my desktop)

`File {
    name: "XXXXX",
    lastModified: XXXXX,
    lastModifiedDate: XXXXX,
    webkitRelativePath: "",
    size: XXXXX,
    type: "application/XXXXX"
}`

Due to security reasons a full path from your PC is not included in file informations.

Comment: then can you tell me the way that I can be able to perform operations on browse file.

Comment: What kind of operation do you need to do? If you need to upload it you have to send POST request using a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` enabled to a script (PHP, Ruby or whatever you're using). I don't think there's anything else to do with a file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `path` property for the [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object. You can only get the path of the file relative to the site's URL.

There are the available properties.

- **`File.lastModified`** (Read only)

  > Returns the last modified time of the file, in millisecond since the UNIX epoch (January 1st, 1970 at Midnight).
- **`File.lastModifiedDate`** (Read only)

  > Returns the last modified Date of the file referenced by the File object.
- **`File.name`** (Read only)

  > Returns the name of the file referenced by the File object.
- **`File.webkitRelativePath`** Read only)

  > Returns the path the URL of the File is relative to.

File implements `Blob`, so it also has the following properties available to it:

- **`File.size`** (Read only)

  > Returns the size of the file.
- **`File.type`** (Read only)

  > Returns the MIME type of the file.